# how to change size of viewport of content in iframe

Tags: iframe, viewport

I want to change the size of the window in iframe. the iframe contains galery of pictures. By cliking on the picture the picture gets bigger up to the size of the window. (like fancyBox)
I need the picture to adapt to the size of the viewport of the iframe and I cant do anything with the content of the page which is the source for the iframe.

how can I make it and is it even possible

example http://jsfiddle.net/SVqx9/18/

just click on the bag and you'll see. I need hide the top of the page because it doesnt look nice to have it there to I need the
    `margin-top: -290px;`
or at least I think I need it ? in order to move the top border of the content little bit up.

Thanks

Comment: You can not manipulate content embedded from other domains from your page.

Comment: I dont want to manipulate the content I need that the iframe will act as real window of browser. for me it means that the picture at the slider will adapt to the size of the iframe

Comment: Then tell the guys who provide the page you load into the iframe to take care of this.